# How to solve: Recompile with -fPIE error?

Tags: c, makefile

I tried to compile the code with a makefile but this is the error that the terminal shows to me:

```
rm -f test/bst_is_not_empty
rm -f test/ht_sepchain_is_not_empty
rm -f *.o test/*.o
cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic -g -I./include   -c -o test/bst_is_not_empty. test/bst_is_not_empty.c
cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic -g -I./include   -c -o exam.o exam.c
cc -L./lib  test/bst_is_not_empty.o exam.o  -lm -lupoalglib -o test/bst_is_not_empty
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libupoalglib.a(test.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libupoalglib.a(bst.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: test/bst_is_not_empty] Error 1
```

This is the makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic
CFLAGS += -g
CFLAGS += -I./include
LDFLAGS += -L./lib
LDLIBS += -lm -lupoalglib


.PHONY: all clean

all: test/bst_is_not_empty test/ht_sepchain_is_not_empty

test/bst_is_not_empty: test/bst_is_not_empty.o exam.o

test/ht_sepchain_is_not_empty: test/ht_sepchain_is_not_empty.o exam.o

clean:
    $(RM) test/bst_is_not_empty
    $(RM) test/ht_sepchain_is_not_empty
    $(RM) *.o test/*.o
```

The makefile, and all source/header files were provided by my professor (is a test example, so...)
I tried to figure out how to solve this issue but I'm still confused about this error

Comment: Where does the `./lib/libupoalglib.a` come from? Can you recompile it?

Comment: It's a static library given by the professor. I can try to recompile

Answer (score 0):

Try recompile `./lib/libupoalglib.a` with -fPIC